# Reading inputs from file in c

Tags: c, file-io

I have this block of code:

```c
    Meal* Menu = NULL;
    int funcNum,amount,tableNum;
    char name[100];
    char* product;
    Meal* tables = (Meal*)malloc(sizeof(Meal) * N);
        
    while((fscanf(Instruction,"%d",&funcNum)) == 1){
            if(funcNum == 1){
                CreateProducts(in,&Menu);
            }
            else if(funcNum == 2){
                fscanf(Instruction, "%s %d", name, &amount);
                product = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name) + 1);
                strcpy(product, name);
                AddItems(product, amount, &Menu);
                free(product);
            }
            else if(funcNum == 3){
                fscanf(Instruction, "%d %s %d", &tableNum, name, &amount);
                product = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name) + 1);
                strcpy(product, name);
                OrderItem(tableNum, product, amount, &tables, &Menu);
                free(product);
            }
            else if(funcNum == 4){
                fscanf(Instruction, "%d %s %d", &tableNum, name, &amount);
                product = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name) + 1);
                strcpy(product, name);
                RemoveItem(tableNum, product, amount,&tables, &Menu);
                free(product);
            }
            else if(funcNum == 5){
                fscanf(Instruction, "%d", &tableNum);
                RemoveTable(tableNum, &tables);
            }
        }
```

and I try to run it on the "Instructions.txt" file, but for some reason when it gets to the 4th line which is "3 5 Pasta 4", it gives me the error:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)

This is what's in the file by the way:

```
1

2 Pasta 4

3 1 Falafel 3

3 5 Fish 3

3 5 Pasta 4

4 5 Fish 3

5 1

5 5
```

Comment: This is tangential but consider using switch statements, and calloc.

Comment: what's `Instruction`? What does `CreateProducts` do? What's `in`? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: What is `in` in `CreateProducts(in, &Menu);`? What do the functions do with `product` which you then `free(product);`? Do you later dereference the memory that you freed? The caller already allocated memory for the local inputs: do your functions do that again?

Comment: @Keanu, `product = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name) + 1); strcpy(product, name); AddItems(product, amount, &Menu); free(product);` makes little sense as `AddItems(name, amount, &Menu);` should suffice.  Why does code allocate?